# Converting int to char?

Tags: char, int, d

```d
ref void init_board (ref int side, ref char[][] board)  //make empty symbol chessboard
{
    const char black = ' ';
    const char white = 0xB0;

    board[0][0] = ' ';
    for (int i = 1; i <= side; i++)
    {
        board[i][0] = 0x30 + i;  //Setting nums; "Error: Cannot convert int to char"
        board[0][i] = 0x40 + i;  //Setting letters; same here
        for (int j = 1; j <= side; j++)
            board[i][j] = (i+j)%2 == 0 ? black : white; //making black-white board
    }
}
```

I'm trying to make a simple symbol chessboard. How do I set nums and letters depending or number of row/column correctly? `board[i][0] = 0x30 + i;` (or 0x40) works in C++, but not in D.

Comment: What does `ref void` do?

Comment: @Kerbiter why are you using ref in there at all? On any of it? `ref int` when it is only being read is a complete waste and `ref char[][]` similarly just adds yet another indirection for no benefit here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You already have what you need in the [std.conv](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_conv.html) module. - The best is to use the [std.conv.to](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_conv.html#.to).

```
import std.conv;
import std.stdio;

void main() {
  int i = 68;
  char a = to!char(i);
  writeln(a);
}
```

Output:

```
D
```

Answer (score 1):

```d
board[i][0] = cast(char)(0x30 + i);
```

Keep in mind that when converting like this, it could overflow.

Comment: Use [`std.conv.to`](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_conv.html#.to) to be warned of overflow on a narrowing conversion.